# How to implement autovivification for Ruby structs?

Tags: ruby, struct, autovivification

Ruby has support for autovivification for hashes by passing a block to `Hash.new`:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 42 }
hash[:foo] += 1   # => 43
```

I'd like to implement autovivification for structs, also. This is the best I can come up with:

```
Foo = Struct.new(:bar) do
  def bar
    self[:bar] ||= 42
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar += 1   # => 43
```

and of course, this only autovivifies the named accessor (`foo.bar`), not the `[]` form (`foo[:bar]`). Is there a better way to implement autovivification for structs, in particular one that works robustly for both the `foo.bar` and `foo[:bar]` forms?

Comment: Your examples are not really equivalent. The hash's default proc is called because `hash` does not have a key `:foo`. The struct instance `foo` on the other hand does have a member `:bar` with an initial value of `nil`.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you, that is very true. And is in fact the key to doing what I need to do: I don't need the lazy-loading aspects of autovivification, just need some fields to be set up to be non-nil. And it turns out that setting up an `initialize` method to set up the initial field values will do just that. Thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the following approach:

```
module StructVivificator
  def self.prepended(base)
    base.send(:define_method, :default_proc) do |&λ|
      instance_variable_set(:@λ, λ)
    end
  end
  def [](name)
    super || @λ && @λ.() # or more sophisticated checks
  end
end

Foo = Struct.new(:bar) do
  prepend StructVivificator
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.default_proc { 42 } # declare a `default_proc` as in Hash

foo[:bar] += 1   # => 43
foo.bar += 1     # => 44
```

`foo.bar` above calls `foo[:bar]` under the hood through `method_missing` magic, so the only thing to overwrite is a `Struct#[]` method.

Prepending a module makes it more robust, per-instance and in general more flexible.

---

The code above is just an example. To copy the behavior of `Hash#default_proc` one might (credits to @Stefan for comments):

```
module StructVivificator
  def self.prepended(base)
    raise 'Sorry, structs only!' unless base < Struct

    base.singleton_class.prepend(Module.new do
      def new(*args, &λ) # override `new` to accept block
        super(*args).tap { @λ = λ }
      end
    end)
    base.send(:define_method, :default_proc=) { |λ| @λ = λ }
    base.send(:define_method, :default_proc) { |&λ| λ ? @λ = λ : @λ }

    # override accessors (additional advantage: performance/clarity)
    base.members.each do |m|
      base.send(:define_method, m) { self[m] }
      base.send(:define_method, "#{m}=") { |value| self[m] = value }
    end
  end
  def [](name)
    super || default_proc && default_proc.(name) # or more sophisticated checks
  end
end
```

Now `default_proc` lambda will receive a `name` to decide how to behave in such a case.

```
Foo = Struct.new(:bar, :baz) do
  prepend StructVivificator
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.default_proc = ->(name) { name == :bar ? 42 : 0 }
puts foo.bar          # => 42
puts foo[:bar] += 1   # => 43
puts foo.bar += 1     # => 44
puts foo[:baz] += 1   # => 1
```

Comment: The `prepended` callback and `send` are not needed. You can define the method via `def default_proc(&λ); @λ = λ; end`, just like `[]`. And you don't even need another module, defining the methods in `Foo` (i.e. within the struct's `do ... end` block) works as well.

Comment: @Stefan yes, I know. There was `base.singleton_class.send(:define_method, :new)`, that copies the `Hash::new` behavior assigning default proc. I have finally removed it for the sake of clarity. The module is needed if there is more than one struct to be vivified. Also, I still find the approach “extend in callback, declare methods in module body” more clear, but it’s definitely a matter of a taste.

Comment: And just overriding `[]` is not enough, if you call `foo.bar` first, it returns `nil`. You also have to override the getter method for each member.

Comment: @Stefan thank you very much, yes, indeed, for an unknown reason `foo.bar` is not defined preliminary, which is weird. Updated.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks for your answer! I ended up going a different path (since I don't need the lazy-loading aspects, only need the values to not be nil, so I just defined an `initialize` method), but your answer does make a lot of sense for situations where some kind of lazy-loading is useful, and I like the module approach.